# Why is synchronizing a method not advisable?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Consider the below code snippet:

```
public class DbSingleton {

    private static volatile DbSingleton instance = null;

    private DbSingleton() {
        if (instance != null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Use getInstance()");
        }
    }

    public static DbSingleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (DbSingleton.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new DbSingleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Why is the above preferred to declaring `getInstance()` as `synchronized`? What does it mean when a method is declared as `synchronized`? Will it synchronize the entire class and slow down the performance?

Comment: It's called [double-checked locking](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking).

Answer (score 1):

If you declare `getInstance` as synchronized, you will pay for the synchronization penalty every time you call `getInstance` even after it is initialized. With this implementation, `getInstance` will never go into a synchronized block after its first call because the instance is initialized already.

Answer (score 1):

Acquiring a lock is expensive. In the given code, a lock is only acquired if `instance == null`.

Consider the following

1. Thread A calls getInstance()
2. Thread B calls getInstance()
3. Thread A acquires the lock
4. Thread B waits on the lock
5. Thread A checks that `instance == null` initializes it, and releases the lock
6. Thread B acquires the lock
7. Thread B checks that `instance != null` and returns instance.

This scenario will happen with either a synchronized method or double checked locking. However, after the instance has been instantiated, consider the difference.

(This is the same as `public static synchronized DbSingleton getInstance()`)

```
public static DbSingleton getInstance() {
    synchronized (DbSingleton.class) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DbSingleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

With this method, after instance has been initialized..

1. Thread A calls getInstance, acquires the lock, returns instance, and releases the lock
2. Thread B calls getInstance, acquires the lock, returns instance, and releases the lock
3. etc.

However, acquiring the lock is redundant in this case, which is the purpose of this code:

```
public static DbSingleton getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized (DbSingleton.class) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new DbSingleton();
            }
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

If instance does not equal null, a lock is never acquired and the flow looks like

1. Thread A calls getInstance and returns instance **(no lock)**
2. Thread B calls getInstance and returns instance **(no lock)**

Answer (score 0):

Double-checked locking is evil and unnecessary, as is the Singleton antipattern. Also, initializing the static variable to `null` is a bad idea. Just initialize the variable as a final variable, or use an enum.

```
private static final DbSingleton instance = new DbSingleton();
…
public static DbSingleton getInstance() {
    return instance;
}
```

The instance is already lazily initialized when the class is, so any additional effort to accomplish that is stupid.